# Does Python use a compiler or interpreter or a combination?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, interpreter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CPython is bytecode interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644619/cpython-is-bytecode-interpreter)

My question is:

Does Python use a compiler, an interpreter or a combination of them?

Comment: cpython uses VM: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-bytecode

Answer (score 2):

Python uses a virtual machine aproach (as PHP, Ruby, .NET languages etc), python implementation uses a compiler to create intermediate language that is executed on a virtual machine.

Answer (score -1):

yes it use an interpreter, just run the .py and then it will be ecxecuted! if you want to compile your script to run on another machine as a .exe program you can compile it with th py2exe library

Comment: -1 it uses a compiler and then executes the bytecode on a virtual machine. look at the `dis` module from the standard library